# Movie with 4 Teens Near a Haunted Place?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Looking for a movie I saw glimpses of.

Four teens (I'm pretty sure three male and one female) are near a haunted place. The first glimpse I saw, was they were all standing in front of a big mountain. Another scene, they're standing with a bunch of stick houses (made of something like tree branches) around and a man in black with black hair comes out of nowhere and keeps haunting them with a sword at their throats. At one point one of the boys rides a stingray-like creature in the sky. A big vine tries to whip them and another creepy guy with red scars all over his face haunts them.

That's pretty much all the parts I saw; It was just yesterday at a doctor's office, so we were all over the place. This is mostly a kid's place, so I don't think it was rated R. From the parts I saw, it did not look like an old movie at all. It was live action. The monster they rode looked like today's technology.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, when did you see this?

Comment: When did you see it? Where did you see it? Anything that might help, check the guide. If you can't get back onto your original account though you need to merge them, see: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: This was a live-action film, not a cartoon? And by "stick houses", do you mean they were made out of something like bamboo?

Comment: Yes, live action film. And the houses were made of like branches of a tree.

Comment: Might be cabin in the woods. It's a horror comedy so it makes more sense you'd see this in a dentist's waiting area. Some of the details (mountain, boy riding in the sky, red scars = clown?) feel familiar, but I've seen it a few years ago.